# isomorphism in rest classes

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic

how can i Show, that if $n$ and $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ are prime...
the rest classes $\mathbb{Z} /nm \mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z} /n \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} /m \mathbb{Z}$ are isomorphic?

And is$  \mathbb{Z} /8\mathbb{Z} $ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} /2 \mathbb{Z}$?
Or is $\mathbb{Z} /8 \mathbb{Z}$ isomorpic to  $\mathbb{Z} /2 \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} /2 \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} /2 \mathbb{Z}$?

I have read a lot about it on the Internet...but im still not sure about this :( hope someone can help. Thanks :)

Comment: Consider a map Z to Z/nZ × Z/mZ carrying an element x to (x, x). Can you show the desired isomorphism using the 1st isomorphism theorem?

Comment: You might look at the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the map $\varphi\colon\mathbb{Z}/mn\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ defined by:
$$\varphi(x\bmod mn)=(x\bmod m,x\bmod n).$$
Show that $\varphi$ is well-defined, namely that the image of $x\bmod mn$ does not depend on the lift in $\mathbb{Z}$, you will used that $m\vert mn$ and $n\vert mn$. Then, it is easily checked that $\varphi$ is a ring homomorphism, therefore by cardinality, it is an isomorphism if and only if it is injective which follows from the following fact:

> If $m|x$ and $n|x$, then $mn|x$, since $m$ and $n$ are coprime.

Which is derived from:

> If $a\vert bc$ and $a$ and $b$ are coprime, then $a\vert c$.

Actually, one can build explicitly the inverse for $\varphi$ using Bezout's theorem. There exists $(u,v)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ such that $um+vn=1$, now let define $\Psi\colon\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}/mn\mathbb{Z}$ by:
$$\Psi(x\bmod m,y\bmod n)=xvn+yum\bmod mn.$$
Show that $\Psi$ is well-defined and that $\varphi\circ\Psi$ and $\Psi\circ\varphi$ are the identity maps.

There is no chance for $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ to be isomorphic, they don't even have the same cardinality.

In $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$ there is an element of order $8$, what about $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^3$?

Comment: "Gauss's lemma" is highly overloaded (and its denotation varies by language). Better to spell it out.

Comment: @BillDubuque You are right, I have done so now.